# How do I remove dependencies to 3rd party code when unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, dependencies

I've got some code that performs some legacy 'database' operation and then processes the result. I want to write a unit test that checks the method that calls the legacy code without interacting with the 'database'.

My code looks something like this:

```
    public static bool CallRoutine(LegacySession session, /* routine params*/)
    {
        try
        {
            LegacyRoutine routine = session.CreateRoutine(/* routine params */);

            routine.Call();

            // Process result

        }
        catch (LegacyException ex)
        {
            // Perform error handling
        }
    }
```

Were this all my code, I would create interfaces that the `LegacySession` and `LegacyRoutine` implement and then write unit tests that use mock implementations of those interfaces using MOQ or something similar. The problem is that I don't have access to the code for `LegacyRoutine` or `LegacySession` so I can't  make them implement an interface.

Any ideas about how I could do this without changing the production code too much?

Comment: Have you looked into mocking libraries like Moq: http://code.google.com/p/moq/

Comment: @Kane: I was intending to use Moq but I thought I needed to derive the classes to be 'Moqed' from an interface to do that? I can't change either of the Legacy... classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't access **LegacyRoutine** (i'm guessing it's in a referenced DLL), why not just create a wrapper for it, then flick on/off different implementations:

```
public interface ILegacyWrapper
{
   ILegacyRoutine CreateRoutine(); 
   // etc etc
}

public interface ILegacyRoutine
{
   // put members of LegacyRoutine
}
```

Know what i mean? Just mock everything out into wrappers/interfaces.

Then you could go:

```
ILegacyRoutine routine = session.CreateRoutine(/* routine params */)
```

Where **session** would be declared as an **ILegacyWrapper**, but implemented with a mock concrete.

Also, it goes without saying (but i'll say it anyway), you should consider a DI framework to make your life simpler. Otherwise you'll end with `IFoo foo = new Foo()` (hard-coded injection) all over the place.

[StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) is my DI poison of choice.

HTH

Comment: I guess this is the way to go - create a wrapper around the session, I was hoping there would be some cunning trickery that would avoid the need to create a whole new set of wrapper classes as this stuff is used in a lot of places and they will need to all be changed over manually.

Comment: This is why you use Dependency Injection. That way you only need to change 1 place (Registry). Let me know if you find a better option, but this is the only way i can see.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a thin wrapper over their API for which you *did* have an interface.  Whether that's a practical thing to do or not rather depends on the size of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Search for C# mock concrete types. Sorry, I have to run, but here's a link to the first thing I found that will solve your problem (there may be better solutions, but this looks OK):

http://docs.typemock.com/isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/CreatingFakesWithAAA.html

Also, check out Moq, which I've had great success with in the past

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a depedency injection framework. It helps you to make your classes more loosely copuled by breaking out external class dependencies into objects which are injected into your classes. These objects are often represented by an interface, which helps you to use different implementations in production and when testing. That way you won't have to actually call the external database when testing. I can recommend [Ninject](http://ninject.org/). It's makes dependency injection a lot easier than doing it manually.